# expected np.ndarray (got int)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I got this error i was trying to create an Actor Critic reinforcement learning algorithm using open AI Frozen Lake gym environment

```
def forward(self,x):
        print("values of x here is ",x)
        x= torch.from_numpy(x).float()
        y= F.relu(self.layerOne(x))
        y= F.relu(self.layerTwo(y))
        action_prob_dist = F.log_softmax(self.action_layer(y),dim=0)
        c = F.relu(self.layerThree(y.detach))
        state_value = torch.tanh(self.value_layer(c))
        
        action_dist = Categorical(actions_prob_dist)
        action = action_dist.sample()
        
        self.log_probs.append(action_dist.log_prob(action))
        self.state_values.append(state_value)
        
        return action.item()
```

Here is the error that i am getting

```
Input In [14], in ActorCritic.forward(self, x)
     12 def forward(self,x):
     13     print("values of x here is ",x)
---> 14     x= torch.from_numpy(x).float()
     15     y= F.relu(self.layerOne(x))
     16     y= F.relu(self.layerTwo(y))

TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got int)
```

Comment: It seems that the type of input x is int. 
Try: x = np.array([x])

Comment: i get this error TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray

Comment: First, use x = np.array([x]) inside the forward function. If that doesn't work, try deleting the line x= torch.from_numpy(x).float() and running.

Comment: still not working